# Removing sql server instances

Tags: sql-server-2008

I was trying to install SQL server 2008, but I couldn't manage to install SQL Management Studio, and I ended up going through the installation process 3 times before I got it installed properly, but now I have these extra instances of SQL Server installed that I don't need. I followed the instructions on MSDN but all that says to do is go through the Add/Remove programs, which uninstalls SQL server but doesn't remove the instances.  Anyone know of a good way to get rid of the additional instances?

Comment: This question belongs to http://serverfault.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They appear as services, if you look through your registry to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\CurrentControLSet\service there will be items for each instance. You can of course, just delete them. as SQL its self is still wanted, but the service just starts another copy with an instance name as a parameter. Eg sqlservr.exe -myInstance